# Php Mysql prepared Statements not working since uploading to produktion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Worked in xampp without any Problem. Uploaded to Strato now it won't work anymore.
Also, it stops building the rest of the Site but no error.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tuerchen WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET["day"]);
$stmt->execute();          

//Reaches here

$result = $stmt->get_result();

//Wont reach here


$fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Enable error reporting. You are missing mysqlnd extension. You need to fix your configuration.

Comment: I suppose the 'i' should be 1 (one) and that it worked in your local environment was rather by accident. Good luck with your Advent calendar ;-)

Comment: @marcus.kreusch The `i` in `bind_param` is correct.

Comment: @Dharman Sorry, I missed the mysqli tag and was assuming pdo - my fault

Comment: @marcus.kreusch Even in PDO that would not work.